# Float numbers from database shows slash instead of dot

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, collation, regional-settings

I read float numbers from float filed in SQL server 2012 and show them in html (using classic-asp and ODBC DSN) . The numbers are stored by separating dots e.g. `3.4` but when I write them into input fields it shows `3/4`. I have set input field `type="mobile"` but I believe this is not the reason because the source code also shows `3/4`.

Database Collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` and when I check data using SSMS it shows **dot** as separator..  Also in windows Regional Settings , the decimal symbol for numbers are set to **dot**. Which more settings I should check for this problem?

**Edit:** this problems happens only in windows 10. Same configuration in windows 7 shows **dots**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS settings in clasic **ASP** settings, I set the Locale ID to **1033** instead of default 0 and the problem gone however I don't know what is the meaning of 0 where I expect it to read default settings from windows locale settings.

Comment: If it is `0` it reads the regional settings from the server it is running on.

Comment: regional settings in my server is in US English and there is no option to show decimal separators using `slash`. It is set to `dot` @Lankymart